# Rabbitmq federation delete messages

Tags: rabbitmq, federation, standby

I'm planning to use rabbitmq federation plugin to replicate messages from master data center to standby, so I can't use cluster mirrored queues.
Is it possible to replicate message deletion to auto sync queue?

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to replicate message from one queue to many consumers use an shovel to map the desired queue to a fanout exchange...then consume directly from the exchange using exclusive queues for each consumer